# Definite integral of $\sqrt x * \exp \left( \frac{-x}{2\theta} \right)$?

Tags: definite-integrals

How do I integrate $$ \int^{\infty}_0 \sqrt x * \exp \left( \frac{-x}{2\theta} \right) dx$$ $\theta$ is a strictly positive constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=2 \theta  t^2$ to make
$$I=\int\sqrt{x} e^{-\frac{x}{2 \theta }}\,dx=4 \sqrt{2}\, \theta ^{3/2} \int e^{-t^2} t^2\,dt$$

Now, integrate by parts
$$\int e^{-t^2} t^2\,dt=-\frac{1}{2} e^{-t^2} t+\frac 12 \int e^{-t^2}\,dt=-\frac{1}{2} e^{-t^2} t+\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \,\text{erf}(t) $$ Now, it is very simple to get the definite integral.